# Call a Method inside a For loop an increasing number of times

Tags: c#

The exercise asks for `"` Inside of the loop, call the `CreateTemplate()` method. It takes a number as a parameter that represents what week it is within the project so that when the template is generated it will say Week X at the top, with X representing which week it is."

I managed to call the Method 16 times with:

```
  for (int week = 0; week < 16; week++)
  {
    CreateTemplate(16);
  }

  static void CreateTemplate(int week)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"Week {week}");
      Console.WriteLine("Announcements: \n \n \n ");
      Console.WriteLine("Report Backs: \n \n \n");
      Console.WriteLine("Discussion Items: \n \n \n");
  }
```

This way though in the console it always prints “Week 16”.
How do I make it increment by one each week?

Comment: Check your call to the function... voting to close as typo.

Comment: Right, it always print 16. You need to have something that varies from 1 to 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question right, but if you run it in a for loop, make sure to not pass the literal '16' like in CreateTemplate(16), but provide it with the iterated index, like so:

```
for (int week = 0; week < 16; week++)
{
   CreateTemplate(week);
}
```